# Crystal Report - How to position your labels from database in the CRViewer?

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a timetable view in my CRViewer and I want to arrange the data that I got from my database in the timetable. But I don't have idea how to position them in there.

This is currently what I got [image]

Now for example on the first row I have
    M, 8:00, 9:00, 7, TLE1

I want to put a box in the Monday column and in the row of 8:00 to 9:00, and inside that I want to put "7 - TLE1"

Some says it possible with formula, but I don't know how since I'm a beginner in crystal report. Any help will be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong..for this type of requirements you need to use cross tab functionality in crystal reports.

Take day column in column part and for rows create a formula that will display as 8-9

For values create a formula by concatinating teacher id and subject code